# How to show multiple dates in calendar with Android Studio?

Tags: android, calendar

I want to show a calendar in Android Studio with multiple dates using different colors like this:

[image]

I tried multiple things but it didn't work (found 2 old posts in here but it didn't help me)

Comment: Please share with us what did you try so far so we won't suggest the same things.

Answer (score 0):

You could find a lot of library support that feature on Github, and of course with sample code:

https://github.com/aminography/PrimeDatePicker

https://github.com/savvisingh/DateRangePicker